# Is there an array function which produces more elements than it receives?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If we use `map` on array - we will get the same number of elements.

If we want less elements - we can use `filter`, `find` or `reduce`, depending on situation.

Is there a build in function which would work the other way?

For example, let's say I have an array like this:

```
myArray = [
  {nodes: Array(5)}, // some array with 5 elements
  {nodes: Array(3)},
  {nodes: Array(3)}
]
```

I want to split every array with more than 3 elements into array which maximum 3 elements. So in the end I want to get:

```
splittedArray = [
  {nodes: Array(3)},
  {nodes: Array(2)},
  {nodes: Array(3)},
  {nodes: Array(3)}
]
```

I know how to achive this with looping over `myArray` with `forEach` and pushing items to some new array, but is there some ready-to-go function for it?

Comment: `reduce` can do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but is there some ready-to-go function for it?

Unfortunately not. Other languages (Kotlin for example) , do have a `chunk` method.

However this could be achieved with `.flatMap`, but "good old for loops" work way better here:

```
 const result = [], size = 3;

 for(const { nodes } of myArray) {
    for(let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += size)   
      result.push({ nodes: nodes.slice(i, i + size) });
 }
```

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted, because you answered my main question - there's no function like `chunk` (thank for the name) in js. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using `Array.flatMap()` we iterate the original array, use the `chunks` method (based on `Array.from()`) to split the `nodes` array to multiple arrays, and then map them, and wrap each in an object. The flatMap converts the result back to a single array.

```js
const myArray = [
  {nodes: Array(5)},
  {nodes: Array(3)},
  {nodes: Array(3)}
]

const chunks = chunkSize => arr => Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(arr.length / chunkSize) }, (_, i) =>
  arr.slice(i * chunkSize, (i + 1) * chunkSize)
)

const chunks3 = chunks(3)

const result = myArray.flatMap(o => chunks3(o.nodes).map(nodes => ({ nodes })))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It works, but for me it's too complicated, at least for the problem I want to solve now. But maybe I'll use this approach in some other situation :)

Answer (score 1):

`map`, `filter` and `find` callbacks only return a boolean, and the method itself decides what to return in the end. With `reduce`, your callback can return anything, and exactly that will be the return value of `reduce`. So:

```js
console.log(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].reduce((a, i) => [...a, ...a, i], []))
```

An example of a `reduce` which produces more elements than its input has.

Comment: Not just `reduce` ... there are better alternatives in this case.

Comment: I forgot that reduce can do things like this, thanks :)